# Query String Filter Configure Connection not responding

Tags: filter, reporting-services, query-string

So I have a `Query String (URL) Filter`, and a `SSRS Report Viewer`. I am trying to connect these two and a `Configure Connection -- Webpage Dialog` pops up and I can't do anything to my IE now. 
[image: Configure Connection -- Webpage Dialog]
Normally I would expect this dialog to show some configuration settings and I can click "OK" when I'm done, but this one stays empty forever (it's been blank for at least 20 minutes now). I've tried closing it and re-connecting but it's still like this. Anyone has an idea what might cause this and how to solve it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Turns out that I gave the report view a wrong url to the report. Should have just give me a warning Microsoft!

Comment: You should add your comment as an answer so you will be able to mark it as your accepted answer later on

Comment: You are absolutely correct but I wasn't able to answer my questions within 8 hours since I had no rep :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I gave the report view a wrong url to the report. Should have just give me a warning Microsoft!

Answer (score 0):

If you connect the report URL to a filter web part before trying to connect hte report parameter(s), you'll get the blank dialog. It doesn't acknowledge the report name bound to the URL, so it seems an empty URL for the report. Without the report URL, it cannot offer choices to bind the parameter(s). My workaround was to input a fixed report URL, then I could connect the report parameter to an external filter. Next I rebound the report URL. But then the parameter binding stopped working. I guess this is not possible.